# Difference Matrix between all elements of a column

Tags: r, matrix, distance, difference

I have a data frame `df`

```
ID  scores
1   2.1
2   1.3
3   -1
4   -3
5   2.4
```

I am interested in calculating a difference matrix that contains the difference of each element from the column `scores` with every element of the same column (including itself).

My desired output is something like this:

```
    1     2    3    4    5
1   0     0.8  3.1  5.1 -0.3
2  -0.8   0    2.3  4.3 -1.1
3  -3.1  -2.3  0    2   -3.4
4  -5.1  -4.3 -2    0   -5.4
5   0.3   1.1  3.4  5.4  0
```

The following post is relevant but asks to compute the differences in another way [Find the differences in all possible ways of list elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55220350/find-the-differences-in-all-possible-ways-of-list-elements)

Is there an easy way to achieve this output, perhaps by using `dplyr` or some built-in function? Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Another option: `dist(df$scores, diag=TRUE, upper=TRUE)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `outer`, which is a base R function for passing all pairwise combinations of the elements of two vectors to a binary function such as `-`:

```r
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:5, scores = c(2.1, 1.3, -1, -3, 2.4))

outer(df$scores, df$scores, `-`)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.0  0.8  3.1  5.1 -0.3
[2,] -0.8  0.0  2.3  4.3 -1.1
[3,] -3.1 -2.3  0.0  2.0 -3.4
[4,] -5.1 -4.3 -2.0  0.0 -5.4
[5,]  0.3  1.1  3.4  5.4  0.0
```

Comment: Such a sophisticated answer, thank you!